How to install QGIS on RedHat 9
I want to install QGIS on a new Linux server running RedHat 9 but dnf didn't find it, and the QGIS website lists specific instructions for some distros, but not RedHat.
Do I have to use flatpak or something similar to install it?  The previous server used flatpak, requiring my predecessor to define "qgis" as a function calling flatpak in order to launch from the command line.  Is there a more direct way?

install flatpak on RedHat9 https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/administering_the_system_using_the_gnome_desktop_environment/assembly_installing-applications-using-flatpak_administering-the-system-using-the-gnome-desktop-environment then https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#flatpak
